# Posts edited and reputation count went down for unknown reason

Tags: support, edits, reputation

I logged onto SO this morning, and noticed that my posts edited count and reputation went down without any notifications indicating that my reputation count(should be ~172) has gone down, or why the edit count was deducted.

Also, one of my questions was deleted as "abandoned", however the question only ever got one downvote(no ups), and if anything, my reputation should've gone **up** because of that, and it doesn't explain why my edit count(should be 43 now) went down.

Why did this happen?

Comment: Don't do [these stats](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10976548/vakore?tab=reputation) explain what happened for you?

Comment: No, actually. Some stats seemed to have somehow disapeared all on the same day with no explanation. :/

Comment: There is no notification for every event. You lose reputation when you get downvotes and your edit count may get down when an edited post is deleted. (but the latter is just an assumption, I'm not 100% sure on that).

Comment: @Tom There was no notif for downvoted. It just mysteriously went down.

Comment: @Vakore Edits earn you points. Two points per approved edit. If the post is deleted, so is all the rep associated with that post. If you earned points for editing a post and those edits were approved, and later the post was deleted, you lose the points as well as the edit counts.

Comment: @Dan Bron I quess the amount my edit count went down matches the amount my reputation went down, but it doesn't explain why it all happened within ~14 hours. *I'm a detective, I'm not allowed to believe in coincidence.*

Comment: Like I said, there is no notification of _every_ event. So don't be surprised to not get a notification when losing points for whatever reasons.

Comment: @Tom 8 edits in ~14 hours. I'm asked *why* it happened. Was there some sort of system clean-up that deleted various "abandoned" questions like mine on the same day?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, it was the result of the system deleting posts that fit the cryteria for deletion, and those were posts I edited. I lost the rep because the posts which I edited were deleted.

Comment: For more information about "the system deleting posts that fit the criteria for deletion: [What is Roomba?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)